# Query Non Inventory Items QuickBooks Desktop

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

How do I query non-inventory items using QuickBooks Desktop IPP SDK? My code only gets the service items and discounts:

```
                ItemConsolidatedQuery itQuery = new ItemConsolidatedQuery();
            itQuery.NameContains = theName;
            var itemsList = itQuery.ExecuteQuery<ItemConsolidated>(dataServices.ServiceContext).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

ItemConsolidated *should* get you all items, including non-inventory items.

If you're *sure* that you aren't getting any non-inventory items back, and that Sync Manager has run recently, and that you're hitting the correct realmID (F2 in QuickBooks will show you the realm ID of the QuickBooks file) then I would submit a support ticket to Intuit.

Answer (score 0):

NonInventory Item is displayed on querying ItemConsolidated entity. It will be under the type “Product” item.

Can you please try to test this use case using apiexplorer tool.
Link - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBD

PFB a sample request

```
<ItemConsolidated>
<Id idDomain="QB">24</Id>
<SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
<MetaData>
<CreatedBy>app</CreatedBy>
<CreateTime>1999-07-29T18:24:16.0Z</CreateTime>
<LastModifiedBy>app</LastModifiedBy>
<LastUpdatedTime>2007-05-05T16:42:40.0Z</LastUpdatedTime>
</MetaData>
<ExternalKey idDomain="QB">24</ExternalKey>
<Synchronized>true</Synchronized>
<Name>Appliance</Name>
<Active>true</Active>
<UnitPrice>
<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
<Amount>0</Amount>
</UnitPrice>
<Type>Product</Type>
<SalesTaxCodeId idDomain="QB">1</SalesTaxCodeId>
<SalesTaxCodeName>Tax</SalesTaxCodeName>
</ItemConsolidated>
```

Doc Ref -https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/itemconsolidated

Comment: Hi, I believe you're suggesting this code:                 dataServices.FindAll(new ItemConsolidated(), 0, 100);
If the customer has about 1000 items, I'd have to pull them all and I would prefer not to do that. Is there another way?

Comment: Hi Joseph, In v2 the only way to get non-inventory items is to use client side filtering. That is - get all items and then use 'Type' as a filter with 'Product' as value.
fyi - In V3, you will able to pass type filter as part of the request.